# can't send data from ajax to controller

Tags: magento2, ajax

in my case I have a controller and an Ajax data sending, but when I check the code the AJAX doesn't send anything and Magento doesn't enter to my controller, is it a problem of routing or what, this is my code :

> Custom/Sales/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <!--Use router 'standard' for frontend route-->
    <router id="standard">
        <!--Define a custom route with id and frontName-->
        <route frontName="customsales" id="customsales">
            <!--The module which this route match to-->
            <module name="Custom_Sales"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> my js file

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/model/agreements-assigner',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
    'mage/url',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
    'uiRegistry'
], function (
    $,
    wrapper,
    agreementsAssigner,
    quote,
    customer,
    urlBuilder,
    urlFormatter,
    errorProcessor,
    registry
) {
    'use strict';

    return function (placeOrderAction) {
      

        /** Override default place order action and add agreement_ids to request */
        return wrapper.wrap(placeOrderAction, function (originalAction, paymentData, messageContainer) {
            agreementsAssigner(paymentData);
            var isCustomer = customer.isLoggedIn();
            var quoteId = quote.getQuoteId();

            var url = urlFormatter.build('customsales/quote/save');
           

            var bookingDate = $('[name="booking_date"]').val();

            if (bookingDate) {

                var payload = {
                    'cartId': quoteId,
                    'booking_date': bookingDate,
                    'is_customer': isCustomer
                };

                if (!payload.booking_date) {
                    return true;
                }

                var result = true;

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: payload,
                    dataType: 'text',
                    type: 'POST',
                }).done(
                    function (response) {
                        result = true;
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        result = false;
                        errorProcessor.process(response);
                    }
                );
            }

            return originalAction(paymentData, messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```

> update : controller code

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Sales\Controller\Quote;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $quoteIdMaskFactory;

    protected $quoteRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->quoteIdMaskFactory = $quoteIdMaskFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if ($post) {
            $cartId       = $post['cartId'];
            $bookingDate = $post['booking_date'];
            $loggin       = $post['is_customer'];

            if ($loggin === 'false') {
                $cartId = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($cartId, 'masked_id')->getQuoteId();
            }

            $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
            if (!$quote->getItemsCount()) {
                throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Cart %1 doesn\'t contain booking', $cartId));
            }

            $quote->setData('booking_date', $bookingDate);
            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check var/report folder. It might be generate report or check exception.log or system.log

Answer (score 0):

If controller return 404 then check below solution.

Please run below command and check again.

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it gives me error 500 not 404

Comment: add your cotroller code

Comment: see my controller code above

Answer (score 0):

Update your controller code as below. it's ajax based controller you need to return json response.

```
<?php
    
    namespace Custom\Sales\Controller\Quote;
    
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
    
    class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        protected $quoteIdMaskFactory;
    
        protected $quoteRepository;
    
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory,
            \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
            $this->quoteIdMaskFactory = $quoteIdMaskFactory;
        }
    
        /**
         * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw
         */
        public function execute()
        {
    
            $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            if ($post) {
                $cartId       = $post['cartId'];
                $bookingDate = $post['booking_date'];
                $loggin       = $post['is_customer'];
    
                if ($loggin === 'false') {
                    $cartId = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($cartId, 'masked_id')->getQuoteId();
                }
    
                $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
                if (!$quote->getItemsCount()) {
                    throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Cart %1 doesn\'t contain booking', $cartId));
                }
    
                $quote->setData('booking_date', $bookingDate);
                $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
    
                $response = $this->resultFactory
                    ->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)
                    ->setData([
                        'status'  => "done",
                        'message' => "data saved successfully"
                    ]);
    
                return $response;
    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you , but it's not working also